# Error when calling a user-defined function within a while loop, but not when called directly

Tags: r, math, while-loop, colors, user-defined-functions

When I call the user defined function `sRGB_to_CAM16UCS` in the console, it displays the result as intended. But when I try to call it within a while loop it throws an error. Can somebody help me understand the error?

```
library(purrr) 
library(tibble)
library(tidyr) 

sRGB_to_CAM16UCS <- function(R255, G255, B255){
  # Convert sRGB to 1931 CIE XYZ [IEC 61966-2–1:2003(E)]
  ## Convert to the range of 0 to 1
  R1 <- R255 / 255
  G1 <- G255 / 255
  B1 <- B255 / 255
  ## Gamma Expansion of sRGB values
  gamma_inverse <- function(RGB1){
    if (RGB1 < -0.04045 | RGB1 > 0.04045){
      ((RGB1 + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4
    } else {
      RGB1/12.92
    }
  }
  R_li <- gamma_inverse(R1)
  G_li <- gamma_inverse(G1)
  B_li <- gamma_inverse(B1)
  # Convert linear RGB values to CIE XYZ
  X <- 41.24 * R_li + 35.76 * G_li + 18.05 * B_li
  Y <- 21.26 * R_li + 71.52 * G_li + 07.22 * B_li
  Z <- 01.93 * R_li + 11.92 * G_li + 95.05 * B_li
  # Convert XYZ to CAM16
  ## User defined Parameters 
  X_w <- 96.4212
  Y_w <- 100
  Z_w <- 82.5188
  L_A <- 40
  Y_b <- 20
  surround <- 2 
  discounting <- FALSE
  ## Predefined functions and constants
  ### M16
  M16 <- matrix(c(0.401288,-0.250268,-0.002079,
                  0.650173, 1.204414, 0.048952,
                 -0.051461, 0.045854, 0.953127), nrow = 3, ncol=3)
  ### lerp
  lerp <- function(a,b,c){
    (1 - c) * a + c * b
  }
  ### Crop 
  crop <- function(a,b,c){
    pmin(pmax(c, a), b)
  }
  ### Define adapt 
  adapt <- function(component){
    con <- (F_L * abs(component) * 0.01)^0.42
    sign(component) * 400 * con / (con + 27.13)
  }  
  ### Define unadapt 
  unadapt <- function(component){
    sign(component) * 100 / F_L * ((27.13* abs(component))/(400-abs(component)))^2.38095238095
  }
  # Calculations
  ## Calculate "c"
  if (surround >=1){
    c <- lerp(0.59, 0.69, surround-1)
  }else{
    c <- lerp(0.525, 0.59, surround)
  } 
  ## Calculate "F" and "N_c"
  if (c >= 0.59){
    N_c <- lerp(0.9, 1.0, (c - 0.59)/.1)
  } else {
    N_c <- lerp(0.8, 0.9, (c - 0.525)/0.065)
  }
  ## Calculate "k"
  k <- 1/(5*L_A + 1)
  ## Calculate F_L
  F_L <- k^4 * L_A + 0.1 * (1-k^4)^2 * (5 * L_A)^0.33333333333
  ## Calculate n
  n <- Y_b / Y_w
  ## Calculate z 
  z <- 1.48 + sqrt(n)
  ## Calculate N_bb 
  N_bb <- 0.725 * n^-0.2
  ## Calculate D
  if (discounting == FALSE){
    D <- crop(0,1,N_c* (1 - 1/3.6 * exp((-L_A - 42)/92)))
  }else {
    D <- 1
  }
  ## Calculate the "RGB_w"
  RGB_w <- matrix(c(M16[1,1] * X_w + M16[1,2] * Y_w + M16[1,3] * Z_w,
                      M16[2,1] * X_w + M16[2,2] * Y_w + M16[2,3] * Z_w,
                    M16[3,1] * X_w + M16[3,2] * Y_w + M16[3,3] * Z_w), nrow = 3, ncol=1)
  # Calculate the "D_RGB"
  D_RGB <- apply(RGB_w, c(1, 2), function(x)((1 - D) * 1 + D * Y_w/x))
  # Calculate the "D_RGB_inv"
  D_RGB_inv <- apply(D_RGB,c(1, 2),function(x)1/x)
  # Calculate the "RGB_cw"  
  RGB_cw <- RGB_w*D_RGB
  # Calculate RGB_aw
  RGB_aw <- apply(RGB_cw, c(1,2), adapt)
  # Calculate A_w
  A_w <- N_bb * ( 2 * RGB_aw[1,1] + RGB_aw[2,1] + 0.05 * RGB_aw[3,1])
  # Calculate RGB_a
  R_a <- adapt((M16[1,1] * X + M16[1,2] * Y + M16[1,3] * Z) * D_RGB[1,1])
  B_a <- adapt((M16[2,1] * X + M16[2,2] * Y + M16[2,3] * Z) * D_RGB[2,1])
  G_a <- adapt((M16[3,1] * X + M16[3,2] * Y + M16[3,3] * Z) * D_RGB[3,1])
  
  # Calculate Hue
  a <-  R_a + (-12 * G_a + B_a) / 11
  b <- (R_a + G_a - 2 * B_a) / 9
  h_rad <- atan2(b, a)
  h_ucs <- h_rad*(180.0/pi)
  
  # Calculate Lightness (J)
  e_t <- 0.25 * (cos(h_rad + 2) + 3.8)
  A <-  N_bb * (2*R_a + G_a + 0.05*B_a)
  J <- 100 * ((A / A_w)^(c*z))
  J_ucs <- 1.7 * J / (1 + 0.007 * J)
  
  # Calculate brightness (Q)
  Q <- 4/c * sqrt(J/100) * (A_w + 4) * (F_L^0.25)
  
  # Calculate chroma (C)
  t <- (5000 / 13 * N_c * N_bb * e_t * sqrt(a*a + b*b)) / (R_a + G_a + 1.05 * B_a + 0.305)
  alpha <- t^0.9*(1.64 - 0.29^n)^0.73
  C <- alpha * sqrt(J/100)
  
  # Calculate colorfulness (M)
  M <- C * F_L^0.25
  M_ucs <- log(1 + 0.0228 * M) / 0.0228
  
  # Calculate redness-greenness(a)
  a_ucs <- M * cos(h_rad)
  
  # Calculate yellowness-blueness(b)
  b_ucs <- M * sin(h_rad)
  
  # Calculate Saturation (s)
  s <- 50 * sqrt(alpha*c /(A_w + 4))
  
  return(tibble(R255, G255, B255, h_ucs, J_ucs ,M_ucs ,a_ucs, b_ucs)) 
}

nc <- 5
rgb_vals <- tibble(r1 = rdunif(nc, b=255, a=0), g1 = rdunif(nc, b=255, a=0), b1 = rdunif(nc, b=255, a=0))

test <- 1 
test_df <- tibble(h_ucs = numeric(), J_ucs = numeric(), M_ucs = numeric(), a_ucs = numeric(), b_ucs = numeric())

while(test <= nrow(rgb_vals)){
  test_r <- sRGB_to_CAM16UCS(rgb_vals[test, 1],rgb_vals[test, 2],rgb_vals[test, 3])
  test_df <- rbind(test_df, test_r)
  test <- test + 1
}

output <- cbind(rgb_vals, test_df)
print(output)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(output, "rgb2camucs.xlsx")
```

threw an error as following

```
Error in atan2(b, a) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> 
> output <- cbind(rgb_vals, test_df)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0
> print(output)
Error in print(output) : object 'output' not found
```

UPDATE: If I wrap the a and b with `as.numeric()` function, it throws the following error message:

```
Error:
! Column names `r1`, `r1`, `r1`, `r1`, `r1`, and 1 more must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "r1" at locations 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, etc.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Comment: print the `test` for every iteration. you will get the iteration at which your loop breaks. then you can look at the data to recreate the problem manually. i'm sure you will find the problem.

Comment: @D.J, I have tried, I also tried to print the class of a and b variables. The code throws an error even before running the first iteration.

Comment: what happens when you run the while loop for only 1 iteration but save `rgb_vals` and `test_df` as different list entries (without `c()`)? the loop only breaks when trying to cocatenate those two

Comment: @D.J You mean if drop `output <- cbind (rgb_vals, test_df)`? I still get the error. Since I wrapped the a and b values with `as.numeric()`, the error message is elaborate, but it still doesn't make any sense to me. You can see the new error message in the original post, as update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `b` and `a` are indeed non-numeric arguments. They are `data.frames`.

- Replacing that line with `h_rad <- atan2(b$r1, a$r1)` makes it work as `class(b$r1)` results in `numeric`. Note that the last line of code where `output` is exported to an XLSX does not work.
- You can also "unpack" your 1x1 `data.frame` using **double brackets** before calling your method, i.e., say `test_r <- sRGB_to_CAM16UCS(rgb_vals[[test, 1]],rgb_vals[[test, 2]],rgb_vals[[test, 3]])`   instead of `test_r <- sRGB_to_CAM16UCS(rgb_vals[test, 1],rgb_vals[test, 2],rgb_vals[test, 3])`  near the end of your code. This way you are passing the plain numbers to your function. **This way, also the export to XLSX works.**

I found this using RStudio's debugger, setting a breakpoint to that line and then entering `class(b)` into the console on the bottom.
[image: Screenshot of RStudio's debugger used for solving this issue]